# Deferred Rendering: Orthographic directional light that has position

Tags: xna, c#, deferred-rendering

Basically I need to code a light for deferred rendering that is a cross between a spotlight and a directional (positionless) light.  It's to be used for sunlight, but because my terrain has overhangs and multiple layers, I can't use a directional light for the sun, as those affect everything in the scene, and do not cast shadows.

I would also prefer that the light uses a full screen pass like directional lights use, rather than rending the light using a cone geometry like spot lights do.

Does anyone have an example of something like this?  I've found a few resources but nothing that clearly shows how to code it up.  Language is irrelevant, but I would prefer C#.  Anything would be great though.